# Return multiple results with same short code

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I added a function in `functions.php` and it works fine for one result with a link mentioned in `$link` however I am trying to display multiple results from similar links with this function. Tried returning array with two variables `$atlantic1` and `$atlantic2` by adding the second link in `$link2` and also tried creating another function with new short code for second result but nothing works.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

```php
function fish($bubbles) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "fin" => get_option('pacific'),
    ), $bubbles));


    $width = " width=\"".$fin['width']."\"";
    $height = " height=\"".$fin['height']."\"";
    $osorientation = " orientationMode=\"manual\"";
    
        
    $link = "https://pacific.local/item/1/A";   
    $path = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $segments = explode('/', rtrim($path, '/'));
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-pacific-js' ); 

    $atlantic = "<fish-info fAdd=\"".$segments[2]."\" fId=\"".$segments[3]."\" network=\"".$network."\"></fish-info>";

    return $atlantic;
    
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_shortcode('pacific', 'fish');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way is pass `link` as a parameter of the shortcode, then call the shortcode two times with specific link.

First of all, change the **fish function**:

```
function fish($atts) {
    // Pay attention, I removed "extract" so $fin is now a key inside $atts
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
      'fin' => get_option('pacific'),
      'item' => 'CHOOSE_A_DEFAULT'
    ), $atts );


    $width = " width=\"".$atts['fin']['width']."\"";
    $height = " height=\"".$atts['fin']['height']."\"";
    $osorientation = " orientationMode=\"manual\"";

    
    $link = "https://pacific.local/item/" . $atts['item'];   
    $path = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $segments = explode('/', rtrim($path, '/'));

    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-pacific-js' ); 

    $atlantic = "<fish-info fAdd=\"".$segments[2]."\" fId=\"".$segments[3]."\" 
    network=\"".$network."\"></fish-info>";

    return $atlantic;

}
```

In the widget where you are calling the short code, youhave probably something like this:

```
[pacific]
```

You have to change it into something like this:

```
[pacific item="1/A"]
[pacific item="2/B"]
```